# Calculate the time between CreationDate and Now Date in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

In facebook, on each status, i can see the time between the creation date and now date. Ex. 1 hour ago, six months ago, 1 year ago,...

So, in my database SQL, i want to create a View that include a column that describe the time between creationDate and NowDate - NVARCHAR(30) may be include the string: 1 day ago, 2 months ago, etc.

I have one solution for compare 2 DateTime variable but it is not clear:

1. I will caculate the time between DateCreation and Now as TimeInterval
2. If TimeInterval < 1 minute -> "Just Now", If TimeInterval >= 1min and <60min -> caculate the minute between 2 TimePoints. Assume that 6 min -> "6min(s) ago"
3. Similarly, for a period of months or years.

Is there any other solution for this.

Comment: What is the exact format you want to display it in?

Comment: Exactly i want, the column (nvarchar): 1 month ago, 2 days ago, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the code similar to below to generate your data. It's not very precise for months as I used 30 days for a month. For years, I used 365 days per year. But I guess that should be precise enough.

```
declare @date1 as datetime = '20131103 13:00:40'
declare @date2 as datetime = '20160208 16:40:45'

select case 
    when datediff(ss, @date1, @date2) < 60 THEN cast(datediff(ss, @date1, @date2) as varchar(max)) + ' seconds ago'
    when datediff(ss, @date1, @date2) < 3600 THEN cast((datediff(ss, @date1, @date2) / 60) as varchar(max)) + ' minutes ago'
    when datediff(ss, @date1, @date2) < 86400 THEN cast((datediff(ss, @date1, @date2) / 3600) as varchar(max)) + ' hours ago'
    when datediff(ss, @date1, @date2) < 2592000 THEN cast((datediff(ss, @date1, @date2) / 86400) as varchar(max)) + ' days ago'
    when datediff(ss, @date1, @date2) < 31536000 THEN cast((datediff(ss, @date1, @date2) / 2592000) as varchar(max)) + ' months ago'
    else cast((datediff(ss, @date1, @date2) / 31536000) as varchar(max)) + ' years ago'
end
```

The numbers in the query come from the number of seconds in:

- minute = 60
- hour = 3600
- day = 86400
- month = 2592000
- year = 31536000

---

An easier version that does not use just seconds is:

```
declare @date1 as datetime = '20131003 13:00:40'
declare @date2 as datetime = '20151101 16:40:45'

select case 
    when datediff(ss, @date1, @date2) < 60 THEN cast(datediff(ss, @date1, @date2) as varchar(max)) + ' seconds ago'
    when datediff(mi, @date1, @date2) < 60 THEN cast((datediff(mi, @date1, @date2)) as varchar(max)) + ' minutes ago'
    when datediff(hh, @date1, @date2) < 24 THEN cast((datediff(hh, @date1, @date2)) as varchar(max)) + ' hours ago'
    when datediff(dd, @date1, @date2) < 30 THEN cast((datediff(dd, @date1, @date2)) as varchar(max)) + ' days ago'
    when datediff(mm, @date1, @date2) < 13 THEN cast((datediff(mm, @date1, @date2)) as varchar(max)) + ' months ago'
    else cast((datediff(yy, @date1, @date2)) as varchar(max)) + ' years ago'
end
```

Comment: I consider that the month 30 days or 31 days, you have any suggestion?

Comment: I don't think it really matters as no one is going to expect precision when it comes to months. A month has 30.4 days on average so it's closer to 30.

Comment: My system is design to decision maker and he/she care about the exactly month or year for balance sheet. Anyway, tks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I would put this in a function like:

```
 create function dbo.TimeDiffToWords(@eventDateTime as DateTime)
    returns varchar(100)
    as 
    begin
    declare @ret varchar(100)
    declare @value int
    declare @done bit

set @done = 0

set @value = datediff(year, @eventDateTime, getdate())

if @value > 0
begin
    set @ret = 'Over '+cast(@value as varchar(6))+' year(s) ago.'
    set @done = 1
end

if @done = 0
begin
  set @value = datediff(month, @eventDateTime, getdate())
    if @value > 0
    begin
        set @ret = 'Over '+cast(@value as varchar(6))+' months(s) ago.'
        set @done = 1
    end
end

if @done = 0
begin
  set @value = datediff(day, @eventDateTime, getdate())
    if @value > 0
    begin
        set @ret = 'Over '+cast(@value as varchar(6))+' days(s) ago.'
        set @done = 1
    end
end

-- continue till down to seconds ago.
if @done = 0
begin
    set @ret = 'Not coded yet.'
end

return @ret

end
```

then you can just call it like this test code does:

```
select dbo.TimeDiffToWords(EventDateTime)
from (select dateadd(month,-40, getdate()) as EventDateTime
    union all select dateadd(day,-40, getdate())
    union all select dateadd(day,-6, getdate())
    union all select dateadd(day,-2, getdate())
    union all select dateadd(hour,-4, getdate())
    union all select dateadd(minute,-2, getdate())
) as testTimes
```